# What is the face to face height of a Acute Golden Rhombohedron?

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am doing the CAD for a Acute Golden Rhombohedron, and I want to form it by having 2 parallel Golden Rhombus, and offset one of them by the long axis (X), and the face to face axis(Z).

I am following the size of the Golden Rhombus here
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-svg/GoldenRhombus_1000.svg

What would be the length of those offsets?

Edit: Using the formula for the volume and area I have work out the height to be $\frac{a\sqrt{5(10+2\sqrt{5})}}{10}$ and I can find the X offset with Pythagoras' theorem. But I would appreciate it if someone can tell me how to work this out without "cheating"

Comment: Before asking the SE, you should try the problem and post your efforts. That way, users can see your grasp on the problem and give you according advice, instead of just giving you the answer!

Comment: I know the formular of the volume of the Rhombohedron, and the area of the Rhombus, so I can work out the height(Z), but I can't figure out the X offset.

Comment: In a right triangle, the product of two catheti is the same as the product of the hypotenuse times its altitude.